# WPF rectangle fill disappears

Tags: wpf, canvas, fill

There was a huge part of question here, but by further investigations I found it's unrelated.

### Preamble

I want to change fill of `Rectangle` dynamicaly from code-behind, so I get canvas defined in resource dictionary (it's Icons.xml from pack MahApps.Metro) and apply to rectangle fill with this icon. I created empty window with rectangle only:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="VKPlaylist.GUI.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300"
>

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="hurrdurr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="190" Margin="53,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193">
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Black" />
            </Rectangle.Resources>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_settings}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Icons.xml entries looks like this:

```
<Canvas Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" x:Key="appbar_add">
        <Path Width="24" Height="24" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 22,12L 26,12L 26,22L 36,22L 36,26L 26,26L 26,36L 22,36L 22,26L 12,26L 12,22L 22,22L 22,12 Z " />
    </Canvas>
```

### Problem

Icon disappears after two-three swaps from code-behind. I used this test:

```
public partial class Window1
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) => 
            new Thread(() => {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => hurrdurr.Fill = new VisualBrush(ResourceProvider.GetIcon("appbar_pause"))));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => hurrdurr.Fill = new VisualBrush(ResourceProvider.GetIcon("appbar_play"))));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => hurrdurr.Fill = new VisualBrush(ResourceProvider.GetIcon("appbar_pause")))); // rectangle became blank on this iteration
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => hurrdurr.Fill = new VisualBrush(ResourceProvider.GetIcon("appbar_play"))));
            }).Start();
    }
}

internal static class ResourceProvider
{
    private static ResourceDictionary Icons;

    public static Canvas GetIcon(string key)
    {
        if (Icons == null)
        {
            Icons = new ResourceDictionary();
            Icons.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/VKPlaylist;component/Resources/Icons.xaml");
        }
        return Icons.Contains(key) ? Icons[key] as Canvas : null;
    }
}
```

It looks like a bug for me, but I don't know if it's bug of WPF or it's consequence of `Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"` manipulation in Icons.xml from MahApps.Metro.

Comment: Could you please show some xaml code (if you have it, of cause)?

Comment: Xaml looks like `<controls:WPStyleButton x:Name="Prev"    Icon="{StaticResource appbar_arrow_left }" />` all other settings set up in code behind.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in how the internal Rect affects look of the control?

Comment: I edited question, it looks like if I put Rectangle on just-created window without any parents, except root Grid, it's still has an issue.

Comment: Well, we still need code of ResourceProvider :)

Comment: @sevenate just switch it to `new VisualBrush((Canvas)FindResource("appbar_play"))`

Comment: Ok, I've got the code from the question history to be precise and it looks like the sample works fine on my machine - the icon changed 4 times and stay visible in the end.

Comment: One thing however I've added is:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Black" /> in the Icons.xaml

Comment: I could send you zipped solution to try it your self if you need.

Comment: I added back ResourceProvider but can,t fix format from cellphone. Well, if this only reproduces on my PC I'll try to test it on more machines tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Just let me know if you will still facing this issue later.

Comment: I'm here, as well as issue. I found that the problem caused by assigning fill color of icon's canvas as DynamicResourse. To be more clear I created demo with minimal code which should describe all as-is. The reason why developers of MahApps.Metro puts DynamicResource to canvas fill is to have ability to easily colorize vector icon into any color separately, without assigning fill on ResourceDictionary level. Demo is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31542635/IconSwapTest.zip And my question stays open: Is it a WPF bug or it designed to work this way?